# Paste special characters to function argument in R

Tags: r, special-characters

I am building function to check if link exists on page (code bellow)

```
kodHTML <- read_html(stronaDoSprawdzenia)
a <- '//a[contains(@href, "https://a.pl/abc/")]'
cast6 <- html_node(kodHTML, xpath = a)
```

Could I use paste function to create dynamicaly value of a?

I tried to use code bellow but this doesnt work

```
z <- paste("'//a[contains(@href,"," \"https://a.pl/abc/")]'")
```

Is it possible to use paste function in this situation ?

Comment: extra double quote in there, use: `paste0("'//a[contains(@href,", " \"https://a.pl/abc/)]'")`

Comment: this return "'//a[contains(@href, \"https://a.pl/abc/)]'" but I need to work "'//a[contains(@href, "https://a.pl/abc/)]'"

Answer (score 0):

I think the code does not work, because you have to "escape" quotation marks.

This is your version:

```
z <- paste("'//a[contains(@href,"," \"https://a.pl/abc/")]'")
```

and you might need this

```
z <- paste("'//a[contains(@href,"," \"https://a.pl/abc/\")]'")
                                                       ^
```

Comment: Consider voting to close questions which only contain typos.

Comment: This return "'//a[contains(@href,  \"https://a.pl/abc/\")]'" not "'//a[contains(@href,  "https://a.pl/abc/")]'"